# Sharing violation on path using xamarin forms

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have attached a file into my application want to the file with in the app. Tried with the following code.

```
var file = Path.Combine(path);

await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest
{
   File = new ReadOnlyFile(file)
});
```

The following exception im getting

> System.IO.IOException: Sharing violation on path
> /storage/emulated/0/Download/1.THE FOX AND THE CRANE NOTES (1).docx
> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode
> mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, Syste

Please anyone help on this.

Comment: Sharing violation means you already have some open access to the file - please **show code** for *"attached a file into my application"* - maybe need `Close` or similar call there.

Comment: Sorry,I did a test ,but I couldn't reproduce this problem on our side. Could you please post more code snippets so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Thanks @ToolmakerSteve Now it's working after Closing the stream.
`var handle = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                    byte[] bytedata = new byte[length];
                   handle.Read(bytedata, 0,(int) length);
                    handle.Close();`